# What necessary buildpacks in heroku-18 to launch Chrome headless=false

Tags: heroku

I am a newbie in Heroku-18 
my buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick
https://github.com/royalgarter/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs-2.0
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
heroku/nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
```

heroku: 18

puppeteer: 1.8.0

project: Node JS

All worked fine for me but I need chrome headless = false

I changed https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome to "https://github.com/royalgarter/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome" then error: libcairo-gobject.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I need another buidpack or a another way to launch Chrome with headless = false.

Thank for help!

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires Chrome to draw the GUI?

Comment: i know heroku-18 don't have GUI, but i need GUI to do capcha step, do you have any trick to do it?